# Limit results when using PHP explode function

Tags: php

I am exploding some information pulled from my database. At the moment it lists all of the 'interests / tags'. Is there a way to limit it to only show 4? and then add a + (remaining amount)

For example :

```
"Interested in : Cats, Dogs, Monkeys (+5)"
```

---

```
<?$tags = explode(',', $usr->interests);

 foreach($tags as $tag):

 ?>

 <? echo "<span>$tag</span>,";
     endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance,
Jamie

Comment: *remaining amount* - amount of what, tags?

Answer (score 1):

The [explode function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) has a `limit` parameter, you can use it:

```
<?php
// Obtain the remaining tags, if the tags count is more than 4
$totalTags = (substr_count($usr->interests, ",") + 1);
$remainingTags = $totalTags > 4 ? $totalTags - 4 : false;

// Obtain the first for 4 tags
$tags = explode(',', $usr->interests, 4-$totalTags); // (third parameter, is the limit)

// Initialize a text buffer
$textBuffer = "";

foreach($tags as $tag){
    // Feed the buffer
    $textBuffer .= "<span>$tag</span>,";
}

// Remove last comma
$textBuffer = substr($textBuffer, 0, strlen($textBuffer)-1);

// Insert remaining counter into the buffer
if($remainingTags){
    $textBuffer = $textBuffer . " (+". $remainingTags .")";
}

// Use your variable wherever you want
echo $textBuffer;

?>
```

Be aware that the `Limit` parameter of the explode should be a negative number to function return only the first 4 tags. See the above link to the function for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for instead

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) :
if (isset($tags[$i]))
echo "<span>" . $tags[$i] . "</span>"
endfor;

if (count($tags) > 4)
echo "(+" . count($tags) - 4 . ")";
```

Or you can use array_slice function to divide the array to tow arrays - first with length of 4, and second with all other elements, then work with this 2 arrays.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php